# converting C code to MIPS problems with recursion and multiplication

Tags: c++, c, mips

hello everyone i need some help converting the following C code into MIPS:

```
main()
{
  int i;
  for (i=0;i<5;++i)
    power(2,1)
    factorial(i)
return 0;
}
int power(int base,int n)
{
  int i,p;
  p=0;
  for(i=1;i<=n;++i)
    p=p*base;
  return p;
}
int factorial(int a)
{
  if(a==1)
    return 1;
  else
  {
    a *=factorial(a-1);
    return a;
  }
}
```

i have only done the factorial part so far but i'm stuck at a*=factorial(a-1), i under stand that multi is used to multiply two registers together but how can it take the input of a recursive loop? also is it possible to multi to multiply with a constant instead of another register?

```
factorial:
addi        $sp, $sp, -8 #adjust stack for 2 items
sw      $ra, 4($sp) #save return address
sw      $a0, 0($sp) #save argument
bne     $a0, 1, Else #if !(a==1), go to else address
addi        $v0, $zero, 1 #result is 1
addi        $sp, $sp, 8 #pop 2 items from stack
jr      $ra     #return
Else:  addi $a0, $a0, -1 #decrement s-1
jal     factorial   #recursive call
lw      $a0, 0($sp) #restore original a
lw      $ra, 4($sp) #and return address
addi        $sp, $sp, 8 #pop two items from stack
```

Comment: also do i have to adjust the stack for main as well or this only done for the functions that main calls?

Comment: Why on earth do you need recursion to calculate factorial?

Comment: Why do you have to do this yourself rather than using the fine compiler?

Comment: it's an assignment, i would have done things differently lol

Comment: @Zack how do i go about doing this? I've read that using a -s flag in a compiler works but would it work if i write this as c++ instead of c?

Comment: If you're using GCC or LLVM I can say for sure that `-S` (not `-s`) makes both the C and C++ compilers emit assembly output.  Don't know about other MIPS compilers, but try it and see!

Comment: Woah it works but it looks way to complicated compared to what where learning in class. thanks any ways zack

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that I wrote, I think it will fit your purpose.

```
.text
factorial:
    li $t0,13       # load 13 to check for overflow
    blt  $a0,$t0,no
    li $v1,1
    no: 
    bgtz $a0,find       # if $a0>0 goto generic case
    li $v0, 1       # base case, 0! = 1 
    jr $ra       
find:   sub $sp,8       # make room for $s0 and $ra
    sw $s0,($sp)        # store argument $s0=n
    sw $ra,4($sp)       # store return address
    move $s0, $a0       # save argument 
    sub $a0, 1      # factorial(n-1) 
    jal factorial       # v0 = (n-1)! 
    mul $v0,$s0,$v0     # n*(n-1)! 
    lw $s0,($sp)            # restore $s0=n
    lw $ra,4($sp)       # restore $ra
    add $sp,8       # reduce stack size
    jr $ra          # return 


main: 
    la $a0,input
    li $v0,4
    syscall
    li $v0,5
    syscall
    move $a0,$v0
    jal factorial
    move $t0,$v1
    bnez $t0,overflow1
    move $a0,$v0
    li $v0,1
    syscall
    b end
    overflow1:
    la $a0,overflow
    li $v0,4
    syscall
    end:
    li $v0,10
    syscall
.data
input:.asciiz"Input a number:"
overflow:.asciiz"There is an overflow!!"
```

It's complete with comments and explanations so there shouldn't be problems.